# Can anyone teach me how to answer this question?

Tags: integration

For any function $f$ continuous on $(-\infty,\infty)$:

$$g(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\,\Bbb dt$$

$$h(x) = \int_0^x (x-t)f(t)\,\Bbb dt$$

$$w(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\sin(x-t)\,\Bbb dt$$

Show that

$$h(x) = \int_0^x g(u)\,\Bbb du$$

and

$$ \frac{\Bbb d^2w}{\Bbb dx^2} + w = f(x) w(0)=0 \text{ , and } w'(0) = 0$$

Comment: First, show us some self work, ideas, effort....second, it'd be a good idea if you go to the FAQ section and learn there a little about how to properly write mathematics with LaTeX in this site.

Comment: Also please use a meaningful title so that others can find your question if they are looking for something similar themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first, note that

$$h(x) = \int_0^x (x-t)f(t)\,dt$$

$$h(x) =x \int_0^xf(t)\,dt-  \int_0^x tf(t)\,dt$$

so that

$$h'(x) = \int_0^xf(t)\,dt+ x f(x)-  x f(x)= \int_0^xf(t)\,dt=g(x)$$

We used FTC and the product rule.

Thus

$$h(x)-h(0)=h(x)=\int_0^x g(u)du$$

For the second one we need a little trickery

$$w(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\sin(x-t)\,dt$$

$$w(x) = \int_0^x f(t)(\sin x \cos t -\sin x \cos t)\,dt$$

$$w(x) =\sin x \int_0^x f(t) \cos t \,dt-\cos x  \int_0^x f(t)\sin t\,dt$$

Now differentiate, using the product rule and FTC.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually no trickery needed : you can differentiate $w(x)$ using the chain rule. If it helps, note $F(x,y) = \int_0^y f(t)\sin (x-t)\,dt$ and remark that $w(x)=F(x,x)$. For example, one obtains
$$
w'(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \cos (x-t)\,dt + f(x)\sin(x-x) = \int_0^x f(t)\cos (x-t).
$$
Now, you should be able to compute $w''(x)$.

Comment: I finally computed w''(x)=f(x)
Is it wrong so I cannote prove d^2w/dx^2 +w = f(x)?

Comment: Indeed,$w''(x) = - \int_0^x f(t)\sin(x-t)\,dt + f(x) \cos (x-x) = f(x) - w(x)$.

Comment: I don't understand why there is a "$$\int_0^x -f(t)sin(x-t)\,dt$$"

Comment: I got it, but I still miss -. I computed w(x)+f(x) ~.~
But I think it may be my careless mistakes~thanks

Comment: What is $\frac{d}{dx} \cos(x)$ ?

Comment: I got it!!!!!!thxxxxxxxxxxx T_T
I got the wrong answer because I made a mistake in the cos(A-B)angle formula

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for the first part
$$ h(x) = \int_0^x g(u)du = \int_{0}^{x} \int_{0}^{u}f(t) \, dt du = \int_{0}^{x} \int_{t}^{x}f(t) \, du dt = \int_{0}^{x} (x-t)f(t) dt.$$

In the above, we changed the order of integration. To see that, plot the region $0<u<x, \,0<t<u$.

Comment: How do you get to $$\int_0^x \int_t^x$$ in the third step?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: I changed the variable of integration to $t$.

Comment: Could you clarify in the post? I don't get how you get those new limits.